# jquery tr selection confusion

Tags: jquery, html

I started working with jQuery again after a few months and am a little confused. I went to [news.ycombinator.com](http://news.ycombinator.com), went to the console in chrome, and typed `$('tr')` to get an array of rows, but it only returned the first row (even though the first table has 3 rows).

When I type `var x = $('tr:odd')` in the chrome console, I get the error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'tr:odd' is not a valid selector.
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Does ycombinator load jQuery?

Comment: on that site jquery isn't in use. You can try experiment on stackoverflow instead. Comment section also has `td`'s :)

Comment: Use `var x = document.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-of-type(odd)')` instead.

Comment: You're seeing the result of Chrome console's built-in `$` operator, which [Returns reference to the first DOM element with the specified CSS selector.](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#selector)

Comment: The site doesn't load jQuery, so you're getting a `$` function that seems to be built into the Chrome Dev Tools. It just calls `document.querySelector`, so it only returns the first matching element, and it doesn't have all the selector extensions that jQuery has.

Comment: Thanks guys - appreciate the quick responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Want an array of all the "tr" tags?

The site doesn't use jQuery. Try with regular Javascript in the console:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
```

That will return an array with all the "tr" tags that exist in the DOM.

To use the "$" to select elements, the site must load jQuery on the header.

Now, what do you want to do with that selection?